# Change language without restart on-the-fly does not work on global declarations

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

The goal is to be able to change language on the fly without having to restart the iOS Swift app.

I am using method swizzling like below to achieve it.

```
method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(Bundle.self, #selector(Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)))!,
            class_getInstanceMethod(Bundle.self, #selector(Bundle.kd_localizedString(key:value:table:)))!
        )
```

This works quite well for NSLocalized Strings for example like below

```
pickOneLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Please choose one to continue..", comment: "")
```

because it is being processed after the language change.

However for global declarations for example like below. It does not work

```
let requestStatuses = [
    "open" : NSLocalizedString("Open Request", comment: ""),
    "accepted" : NSLocalizedString("Booking - Confirmed", comment: ""),
    "rejected" : NSLocalizedString("Booking - Rejected", comment: ""),
    "expired" : NSLocalizedString("Request - Expired", comment: ""),
    "cancelled" : NSLocalizedString("Booking - Cancelled", comment: ""),
    "completed" : NSLocalizedString("Request - Completed", comment: "")
]
```

because above dictionary was declared already, before the labgauge was changed and it stored the original language strings in it. I do not really want to redeclare it because it is redundant and error prone. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but how about using struct?

```
struct RequestStatus {
  let open = NSLocalizedString("Open Request", comment: "")
  // ...
}

let localizedTextOpen = RequestStatus().open // localized string on the fly?
```

Comment: probably a good solution but I will have to change my implementation throughout the project which will be too much.

Comment: what if you change it to ```let requestStatuses = [
    "open" : RequestStatus().open, ...]``` ?